# User Theme Settings File

Tags: interface, theme

blender has some presets by default ( xml files )
and user can save his own settings for theme ( Save User Settings )

[image]

now, 3 simple question

1- is it possible to create an custom xml file to load when blender will open ?

2- where is saved settings file ?

3- where is default blender theme file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default blender theme is located within blender's source code, it is the values used unless a preset theme is used to override them.

The [theme settings used](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/themes.html) at startup are contained within your startup.blend file, you can make any adjustments you like and Save User Settings to have those theme settings active when you start blender.

If you want to create a theme and share it with others, you can create an xml file that contains the theme settings, that others can then use. To start with blender's default theme, click Reset to Default Theme, make any adjustments you like and then click the <kbd>+</kbd> next to the theme list and type in a name to use for your new theme. The xml file created for this can be found under *scripts/presets/interface_theme/* either with your blender install or within your [configuration folder](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html). If you make adjustments, you can click the <kbd>+</kbd> again and enter the same name to update the xml file.

You can find the xml files for the themes that are included with blender inside *scripts/presets/interface_theme* or browse them online [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/interface_theme/), there are also some more themes in the [contrib repository](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/presets/interface_theme/).

Comment: thank you for a complete answer. for default blender theme, can i change source code for values?? which file ???

Comment: You should find them all in [resource.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/interface/resources.c$834) - note that you will need to [build your own](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) version of blender. If you make adjustments to an xml file then you only need to load the theme.

Answer (score 2):

1-Yes,You can import edit your theme or import one from and XML file then press *Save user setting*.

2-Blender save user setting here **"C:\Users\Username\Application data\Blender Foundation\"**

3-There no file for the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a user interface for creating, editing, exporting and importing theme files. You can find it under the *File > User Preferences > Themes* Window.

You can choose from the builtin presets from the dropdown on the top left, or create a new one based on the current using the *+* button to the right of the dropdown menu.

You can also import one from the *Install Theme* button bellow, or reset to the default.

Pressing *Save User Settings* on the bottom left will set the current theme as default for the next startup.