# Accidently deleted a theme

Tags: theme

So I accidentally deleted the Elysium theme with the minus button in blender preferences. Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: I don't think one can recover deleted theme as Blender removes xml file itself. Unless you delete default theme [which is possible to recover](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53696/user-theme-settings-file) and you have no backups other theme files should be downloaded from [online resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53717/1245)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrZak suggested, you can get the files from online resources.

1. Go to the ["interface_theme" folder in the Blender Source Code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/interface_theme/)
2. Copy the contents of the XML file for the theme you want
3. Go to the folder in which blender is installed(usually located in program files)
4. Navigate to "2.79\scripts\presets\interface_theme"
5. Create a new XML file and paste the previously copied item in it